# Using Python and Mechanize to submit data in the website's html

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

I have [this](http://www.mcxindia.com/sitepages/BhavCopyCommodityWise.aspx) website and there are four input boxes which are `Symbol`, `Expiry Date`, `From`, `To`. Now i have written a code to scrape data from the `Symbol` and `Expiry Date` which is like this:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.mcxindia.com/sitepages/BhavCopyCommodityWise.aspx")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
pop = []
pop_dates = []
count = 0
print soup.prettify()

option_list = soup.findAll("option")
#print option_list

for value in option_list:
    #print value
    if value.find(text = True):
        text = ''.join(value.find(text = True))
        text1 = text.encode('ascii')

        if count < 32:  
           pop.append(text1) 

    while count == 32 or count > 32:
        pop_dates.append(text1)
        break

    count = count + 1

print pop
print pop_dates
```

So What i want to do is for `From` and `To` i want to give the dates from my code and it will take that input, use it on the website's html and give the output as usual in that website. How can i do this?? I heard mechanize can do this stuffs but how could i use mechanize in this case??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out something like this:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

br = Browser()
br.set_handle_robots( False )
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.open("http://www.mcxindia.com/sitepages/BhavCopyCommodityWise.aspx")
br.select_form("form1")
#now enter the dates according to your choice
br.form["mTbFromDate"] = "date-From"
br.form["mTbFromDate"] = "date-To"
response = br.submit()
#now read the response with BeautifulSoup and do whatever you want
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read())
```